# IndexError while scraping data

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some data from auction catalogs and keep getting "IndexError: list index out of range" error in line 11. 
First 3 catalogs is going fine, but 4th is getting error and stops working. 
I tried to download it one by one and everything was working, they all have this 'auctionId' element.
What might be the problem?

```
auction_url = 'https://bidspirit-portal.global.ssl.fastly.net//services/portal/getAuctionItems?cacheVersion=2019-04-29_18-10-11&cdnSubDomain=ru&intKey={auction_code}'
for i in range (2000, 2010):
    r = requests.get (auction_url.format(auction_code=i))
    parsed_json = r.json()
    auction_id = parsed_json[0]['auctionId']
    print(auction_id, len(auction_id))
    prices = requests.get('https://ru.bidspirit.com/services/account/getAccountActionsForAuction?auctionId=' + str(auction_id))
    parsed_prices = prices.json()
    with open ('input_%s.json' % i, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        json.dump(parsed_json, f, indent = 2, ensure_ascii=False)
    with open ('prices_%s.json' % i, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f_1:
        json.dump(parsed_prices, f_1, indent = 2, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Result I'm getting

```
5896c87691c917730e76adb6 24
5896c87691c917730e76adb7 24
589729bc91c917730e76b32d 24
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 11, in <module>
    auction_id = parsed_json[0]['auctionId']
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You should print "parsed_json" object and see what it looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes your results are empty. So below should do it

```
import requests
import json

auction_url = 'https://bidspirit-portal.global.ssl.fastly.net//services/portal/getAuctionItems?cacheVersion=2019-04-29_18-10-11&cdnSubDomain=ru&intKey={auction_code}'
for i in range (2000, 2010):
    r = requests.get (auction_url.format(auction_code=i))
    parsed_json = r.json()
    if parsed_json:
        auction_id = parsed_json[0]['auctionId']
        print(auction_id, len(auction_id))
        prices = requests.get('https://ru.bidspirit.com/services/account/getAccountActionsForAuction?auctionId=' + str(auction_id))
        parsed_prices = prices.json()
        with open ('input_%s.json' % i, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            json.dump(parsed_json, f, indent = 2, ensure_ascii=False)
        with open ('prices_%s.json' % i, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f_1:
            json.dump(parsed_prices, f_1, indent = 2, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: Oh, I was so close. Thank you!